# Add query parameter to Retrofit get in Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to use retrofit for get records from my API and it works fine when i do something like this.

> public interface materialAPI {
>
> ```
> @GET("/mlearningServices/Course")
> public void getMaterials(Callback<List<materialClass>> response); }   public void getMaterials()
>  {
>
>      RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Root_Url).build();
>      Log.i(TAG , "hERE IS THE LINK"+adapter.toString());
>      materialAPI api = adapter.create(materialAPI.class);
>      api.getMaterials(new Callback <List<materialClass>>() {
>          @Override
>          public void success(List<materialClass> list, Response response) {
>
>              materials = list;
>              showList();
>              customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
>              listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
>          }
>
>          @Override
>          public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
>
>          }
>      });
>
>  }
> ```

The above code works fine and i can get all my materials but what i want to achieve next is get material with any  id . When a user selects a paticular material, i want to pass the id into the get url so i can get the records

meaning i have to do something like this

```
@GET("/mlearningServices/Course/{myId}")
```

..

How to i add myId to the callback method. This is my first time of using retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Path` annotation

```
@POST("/mlearningServices/Course/{myId}")
public void getMaterials(@Path("myId") String id, Callback<Response> response);
```

References:

- https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html
- http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

That you are asking about is called a `path variable`. To set one, you must rewrite your method signature as this:

```
public void getMaterials(@Path("myId") String id,  Callback<List<materialClass>> response);
```

This way, the variable defined as /path/to/your/endpoint/{nameOfPathVariable} will be injected into that String parameter passed to the method. You could also define it as an Integer, and retrofit will try to cast it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use this to pass your id, Use the @Path annotation

```
@GET("/mlearningServices/Course/{myId}")
Call<materialClass> getMaterials(@Path("myId") String id);
```

@Path is some data that you wish to provide it to GET method before Question Mark ("?") and @Query("..") is some data you wish to provide after "?"

Hope you have understood.